# System.IO.DirectoryNotFoundException after deleting an empty folder and recreating it

Tags: c#, exception, file, copy

I want to copy a folder, and i want to delete destination folder first.
So I am deleting destination folder then recreate it and then copy files.
The problem is that i get the `An unhandled exception of type 'System.IO.DirectoryNotFoundException' occurred in mscorlib.dll`
when trying to copy files. This is the code

```
static public void CopyFolder(string sourceFolder, string destFolder)
    {
        if (Directory.Exists(destFolder)) // check if folde exist
        {
            Directory.Delete(destFolder, true);  // delete folder
        }
        Directory.CreateDirectory(destFolder); // create folder

        string[] files = Directory.GetFiles(sourceFolder);
        foreach (string file in files)
        {
            string name = Path.GetFileName(file);
            string dest = Path.Combine(destFolder, name);
            File.Copy(file, dest, true);
            FileInfo fileinfo = new FileInfo(dest); // get file attrib
            if (fileinfo.Attributes != FileAttributes.ReadOnly) // check if read only 
                File.SetAttributes(dest, FileAttributes.Normal);
        }.......
```

I get the exception in this line `FileInfo fileinfo = new FileInfo(dest);`.

It seems like there is a delay in the creation of the folder and in the mean time I try to copy a file into it. Any clue, what is the problem? The full exception message:

> An unhandled exception of type
>   'System.IO.DirectoryNotFoundException'
>   occurred in mscorlib.dll
>
> Additional information: Could not find
>   a part of the path
>   'C:\Users\joe\Desktop\destfolder\.buildpath'.

### SOLUTION

As it been pointed out by good people, the reason for this exception is that I try recreating the folder before the deletion process is finished.
So the solution is to add 2 lines of code after deletion:

`GC.Collect();
GC.WaitForPendingFinalizers();`

so the correct code will be

```
static public void CopyFolder(string sourceFolder, string destFolder)
{
    if (Directory.Exists(destFolder)) // check if folde exist
    {
        Directory.Delete(destFolder, true);  // delete folder
        GC.Collect();    // CODE ADDED
        GC.WaitForPendingFinalizers(); // CODE ADDED
    }
    Directory.CreateDirectory(destFolder); // create folder

    string[] files = Directory.GetFiles(sourceFolder);
    foreach (string file in files)
    {
        string name = Path.GetFileName(file);
        string dest = Path.Combine(destFolder, name);
        File.Copy(file, dest, true);
        FileInfo fileinfo = new FileInfo(dest); // get file attrib
        if (fileinfo.Attributes != FileAttributes.ReadOnly) // check if read only 
            File.SetAttributes(dest, FileAttributes.Normal);
    }.......
```

This way, you wait with the creation until the deletion process is finished.
Yhanks everyone and especially Saeed.

Comment: Perhaps only delete the contents of the folder if it exists?

Comment: Are you sure the file is being copied?  I would suggest a bit of debug code where you output the source and destination file names before doing the copy, and then output a message that says, "File copied" after the copy is complete.  It seems unlikely that the copy could complete successfully and then the call to `FileInfo` constructor fail.

Comment: When you debug this, what is the value of `dest` on the line which throws the exception?  What are the values of other relevant variables?

Comment: if the destination folder doesnt exist and i run it ,there is no problem. but if the folder exist and it is empty - then i get the exception. dest = "C:\\Users\\.....\\Desktop\\destfolder\\.buildpath"

Comment: What's your exception message? I think there is a security issue, provide full exception message

Comment: An unhandled exception of type 'System.IO.DirectoryNotFoundException' occurred in mscorlib.dll

Additional information: Could not find a part of the path 'C:\Users\joe\Desktop\destfolder\.buildpath'.

Comment: I've added an answer, but just to emphasize: GC.Collect(), GC.WaitForPendingFinalizer() are NOT needed after Directory.Delete.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You got it kinda wrong. The reason for the exception is that there's still a resource that is accessing the folder (or file).

The solution is never `GC.collect()` or `Sleep()`... That's just a work around.
What you're doing is just letting the garbage collector dispose of the resource, and then giving it time to act.

The **RIGHT** way is to manage your own resources. Instead of a static method that you have no control on, use a `using` block and dispose of the resource in the end of the block. This way there's no overhead while your waiting for things that aren't under your control (GC).

Use an object that controls the resources, and the `using` block will dispose it at the end.

In your case, using a single `DirectoryInfo` object that controls that resource should work.

Comment: My mistake, DirectoryInfo isn't disposable. using can only be used on Idisposable objects.

Comment: I dont see how Using will help in my case. I have a tree structure of folders made from a C# program. When the user quites the tree structure must be destroyed. If there are files within this structure the rutines throws the exeception, eventhough I use FORCE delete recursive on the folders. If I use GC.Collect and GC.waitforfinalizers method, I have no problems. How should I convert this to a Using? Make the whole program one big Using?

Comment: @BerggreenDK - No, the fact that gc.collect solves the problem means that there are resources that aren't being disposed of properly, and are disposed when you force their collection. What you do need to do, is keep track of the objects that are created behind the scenes, and dispose of them.

Comment: @YochaiTimmer, if I create two folders, and from Explorer manually drag a file into the subfolder of the two, I can provoke this error. What ressource would it be that I need to release?

Comment: This is wrong. If the GC.Collect method worked because of some resource being garbage collected, that would be a resource which was already available for garbage collection. `using` should not and does not affect this. There is no imaginary resource which has to be wrapped in `using`. My suspicion is that GC.Collect() works only because it has the same effect as doing Sleep().

Comment: This answer is wrong. Use a sleep like @VitalyB suggested. Not very nice at all, but clean and logical.

Answer (score 7):

I am confused about your current solution. GC has nothing to do with deleting a folder, it only works because adding GC related functionality there is similar to adding Thread.Sleep() or a MessageBox. It works only by chance.

Instead, you should wait until the directory is actually deleted, e.g:

```
Directory.Delete(destFolder, true);  // delete folder
while(Directory.Exists(destFolder))
{
Thread.Sleep(100);
}
```

Only once this code finishes, you should continue.

Comment: @SystemPause, First adding GC.Collect() try to collect items, and then adding GC.WaitForPendingFinalizer() waits until the objects created for deleting folder removing from ram, this objects will be removed after the deletion of folder so there is no need to have  Thread.Sleep, It doesn't work by chance it works carefully.

Comment: It seems very strange to me to rely on an inner implementation of Directory.Delete and even more so if you do it using GC. There is no guarantee that inner implementation won't change in the next .NET version. The safest way to go, in my eyes, is the one appearing in my answer. Also, check the discussion on the subject here: http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en/csharpgeneral/thread/a2fcc569-1835-471f-b731-3fe9c6bcd2d9

Comment: There's a lot wrong with the question and the currently accepted solution. This should be the accepted answer.

Comment: @SaeedAmiri is there a link that proves what you claim ?

Comment: @erhan355, I don't know what was the context, since it seems that some comments are deleted over time. But if you are interested to know whether my comments about GC.Collect or GC.WaitForPendingFinalizers are true, then you can check MSDN. But as I remember back then I was working a lot with COM objects and had to deal with GC quite often, so most likely I was right about them, but of course, everyone makes mistakes.

Answer (score 1):

Try using the FileIO method instead, I had the same issue, code below works perfect.

FileIO.FileSystem.DeleteDirectory(directoryName,FileIO.DeleteDirectoryOption.DeleteAllContent)

Comment: interesting, I will give this approach a go to. Funny how there are so many ways to do the same within the .NET API. quite messy.

Comment: I was having this issue, changed over to using the FileIO method and still get the same error.

Answer (score 0):

Why are you setting the file attributes after you have copied the file? Is this necessary?

What you could do is first setting the the different attributes and afterwards doing the actual file copy. It also makes more sense, first checking if it is a ReadOnly file, and if it is, then set it to Normal, and do the copy.

Comment: i am setting the file attrib to normal , because if there is a readonly file i get exception when doing the deletion :p

Answer (score 0):

Sorry for answering and not commenting but my reputation isn't high enought yet. In the MSDN is written, that the path has to be *"well-formed"* http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-gb/library/system.io.fileinfo%28v=VS.90%29.aspx

Maybe trying it out, by putting file in the working directory? So no path is needed and you can see if the problem is in the path or in the file...

Answer (score 0):

Ok This is very strange.
the exception only happen when the destination folder is empty.
but adding the folowing line after the destination folder deletion seem to solve the problem.
the line : 
MessageBox.Show("folder " + destFolder + "folder was deleted", "alert");

```
static public void CopyFolder(string sourceFolder, string destFolder)
    {
        if (Directory.Exists(destFolder)) // check if folder exist
        {
            Directory.Delete(destFolder, true);  // delete folder
            MessageBox.Show("folder " + destFolder + "folder was deleted", "alert");
        }
        Directory.CreateDirectory(destFolder); // create folder

        string[] files = Directory.GetFiles(sourceFolder);
        foreach (string file in files)
        {
            string name = Path.GetFileName(file);
            string dest = Path.Combine(destFolder, name);
            File.Copy(file, dest, true);
            FileInfo fileinfo = new FileInfo(dest); // get file attrib
            if (fileinfo.Attributes != FileAttributes.ReadOnly) // check if read only 
                File.SetAttributes(dest, FileAttributes.Normal);
        }
```

so putting a MessageBox.show after the deletion causes the System.IO.DirectoryNotFoundException to go away. its as if the fact that there is a small delay after the deletion , the recreation of the folder goes well.
i guess i will find a work around this, but if someone knows what is causing this and the way to solve it , i will be very happy to hear it.

Comment: Replace the messagebox with a small sleep. These kinds of errors can occur when the file-system takes some time to do the action you ask it to. So when you do "create", the folder isn't even deleted yet, and so on.

Answer (score 0):

Try to set Fileinfo of dest first, then copy

```
    foreach (string file in files)
    {
        string name = Path.GetFileName(file);
        string dest = Path.Combine(destFolder, name);

        FileInfo fileinfo = new FileInfo(dest); // get file attrib
        dest.Attributes = FileAttributes.Normal;
        File.Copy(file, dest, true);

    }.......
```

Comment: the problem was that the directory was not ready to be used ,if i try this i get the same problem , there is not destination folder.

Comment: I think your program is multithread so when deleting the folder and then recreating it, the thread responsible for copying is started before the other finishing. Why don't you bring the code of directory creation inside the if statement, after the directory deletion.

Comment: I think you are right about the reason that cause this exception ,and saeed already pointed out the solution.now about putting the directory creation inside the if statement - that would be replication of code because i would need another one out of the if statement in case the folder does not exist.